# Название висящей полосы материи

Tags: названия

.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какое имеет название эта полоса материи? Шнур? Тесьма?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае — это язычок. Он крепится к бегунку молнии.